# Table won't stop oscillating in Bullet Physics

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, bulletphysics, assimp

So I have a table that I've loaded in using ASSIMP/OpenGL and I am trying to implement bullet to add physics into my project. However, when the table tries to land it will keep oscillating forever. I'm currently creating a btConvexHullShape to represent my table, and I'm looping through my loaded data and adding each point to the collision shape. Here is my code that does this.

```
btConvexHullShape* tableShape = new btConvexHullShape();

int numMeshes = table.meshes.size();

for (int i = 0; i < numMeshes; i++)
{
    Mesh _tempMesh = table.meshes[i];
    int numVertices = table.meshes[i].vertices.size();

    for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
    {
        glm::vec3 _tempPos = _tempMesh.vertices[j].Position;
        tableShape->addPoint(btVector3(_tempPos.x, _tempPos.y, _tempPos.z));
    }
}

btDefaultMotionState* fallMotionState =
    new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(table.position.x, table.position.y, table.position.z)));
btScalar mass = 1;
btVector3 fallInertia(0, 0, 0);
tableShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, fallInertia);
btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo fallRigidBodyCI(mass, fallMotionState, tableShape, fallInertia);
fallRigidBodyCI.m_restitution = 0;
btRigidBody* fallRigidBody = new btRigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(fallRigidBody);
```

My end goal is to have the table flip realistically. To test this I give the table an impulse:

```
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        fallRigidBody->activate(true);
        fallRigidBody->applyImpulse(btVector3(0,0.5, 0.1), btVector3(0, table.max_y - 0.2, 0));
    }
```

When the table lands, it just keeps oscillating forever. Ideally, I want it to just rest on its side or straight up once it lands. Here is a [GIF](https://i.gyazo.com/84c8d43b5a5e8f010c6984918d34e0f9.gif) of the oscillation.

Comment: just a hunch: did you forget to centre the mesh of your table? make sure the origin is inside the convex hull, otherwise weird effects like yours aren't even that strange. (Think of a pendulum hanging through the floor with your table on top and the centre of mass way down below, then the motion seems about right).

Comment: I think you're completely right, how would you advise I fix this? When I draw my mesh the origin is at the very bottom of the mesh. I set the motion-state of the rigid body at (0, 0, 0) and when I print the initial origin of the transform for the rigid body it's at (0, 0.04, 0).